Space of complex matrices that are both pairwise row and column orthagonal
How can I describe all complex $m \times n$ matrices $A = (a_{ij})$ such that for any two rows $\mathbf{r}_k$ and $\mathbf{r}_l$ (where $\mathbf{r}_k$ denotes the $k$-th row vector of $A$), the following condition holds:
$\sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj} \overline{a_{lj}} = 0 \quad \text{for all} \quad 1 \le k < l \le m$
Similarly, for any two columns $\mathbf{c}_p$ and $\mathbf{c}_q$ (where $\mathbf{c}_p$ denotes the $p$-th column vector of $A$), the following condition holds:
$\sum_{i=1}^m a_{ip} \overline{a_{iq}} = 0 \quad \text{for all} \quad 1 \le p < q \le n$
In other words, I want to describe all complex $m \times n$ matrices $A$ such that the row vectors are pairwise orthogonal with respect to the standard Hermitian inner product, and similarly for the column vectors. The most I can deduce right now is that this space is closed under multiplying any row or column by a complex number with norm 1.

The condition you want is equivalent to the condition that the matrices $A^{\dagger} A$ and $A A^{\dagger}$ are both diagonal, where $(-)^{\dagger}$ denotes the conjugate transpose. If we take a singular value decomposition $A = U \Sigma V^{\dagger}$ of $A$ it follows that
$$A^{\dagger} A = V \Sigma^2 V^{\dagger}$$
$$A A^{\dagger} = U \Sigma^2 U^{\dagger}$$
are diagonal. Since these matrices are orthogonally diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\sigma_i^2$ (the square of the singular values $\sigma_i$ of $A$), they are diagonal iff they are both equal to a permutation of $\Sigma^2$; in particular they must be a permutation of each other.
This means the following. Let $\sigma_1 > \sigma_2 > \dots $ be an enumeration of the distinct singular values of $A$; associated to each of these is a right singular subspace and a left singular subspace
$$R_i = \ker(A^{\dagger} A - \sigma_i^2)$$
$$L_i = \ker(A A^{\dagger} - \sigma_i^2).$$
Orthonormal bases of these are used to write down the SVD. What the condition above means is that the $R_i$ and $L_i$ are the same subspaces up to a permutation of the coordinates, and moreover are both given by some partition of the set of coordinates (corresponding to the eigenspaces of $\Sigma^2$, up to permutation).
An invariant way to describe the SVD is that the $R_i$ and the $L_i$ are an orthogonal decomposition of the source and target space and that $A$ restricts to a collection of isometries $A_i : R_i \to L_i$ with norm $\sigma_i$. This means that the general $A$ satisfying your condition is a "block permutation matrix" (a matrix which can be partitioned into blocks such that exactly one block in each row or column is nonzero) whose nonzero blocks are scalar multiples of unitary matrices. I'm not sure how to write down schematically the general such matrix but for example a block matrix of the form
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \sigma_1 U_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sigma_2 U_2 \\ \sigma_3 U_3 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
where $U_1, U_2, U_3$ are three unitary matrices (of possibly different sizes) would qualify, but we can take an arbitrary permutation.

Does this method also work for higher dimensional tensors?

I have absolutely no idea! There is a higher-order SVD but I don't know anything about it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition).
